# Firebird and stored procedures: if exists then else

Tags: stored-procedures, if-statement, firebird

I'm trying to create a stored procedure for firebird 2.1 (this is the version which is to be used)
But am getting a bit stuck, so any help is appreciated.
The final version should compare 4 values agains the table, and retreive either the primaryid if the value exists, or create the new entry in the table, and return the new primaryid.

But I get stuck with only one value lookup, and it's not even using the variable yet.

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE TESTSP 
 ( A Varchar(64) ) 
RETURNS 
 ( RESULT Integer )
AS 

BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT PRIMARYID FROM TABLENAME WHERE FIELD = 'Some string')) then
    SELECT PRIMARYID FROM TABLENAME WHERE FIELD = 'Some string' into :primaryid;
    result = PRIMARYID;
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD) VALUES ('Some string');
    result = gen_id(GEN_TABLEID, 0);
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

I get a "Token unknown" for the Else command.

Update after responses:
Now I want to use the 4 variables and return the 4 results.
I think I need a for loop to do so, but with firebird, the for function means something else.
So what would be the way to go?

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE TESTSP 
 ( value1 Varchar(64) ) 
RETURNS 
 ( RESULT1 Integer )
AS 

BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT PRIMARYID FROM TABLENAME WHERE FIELD = :value1)) then
        SELECT PRIMARYID FROM TABLENAME WHERE FIELD = value1 into :result1;
    ELSE BEGIN
        result1 = gen_id(GEN_TABLEID, 1);
        INSERT INTO TABLENAME (PRIMARYID, FIELD) VALUES (:result1, :value1);
    END
    suspend;
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tico already answered you have to use `begin / end` to group multiple statements in `then / else` part. The error abut column PRIMARYID being unknown is because you reference to it without having declared a local variable for it. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTSP ( A Varchar(64) ) 
RETURNS ( RESULT Integer )
AS 
BEGIN
  -- initialize the result
  Result = NULL;
  -- check is the string already in table
  SELECT PRIMARYID FROM TABLENAME WHERE FIELD = 'Some string' into :Result;
  IF (Result is NULL) then
    INSERT INTO TABLENAME(PRIMARYID, FIELD) VALUES(gen_id(GEN_TABLEID, 1), 'Some string') RETURNING PRIMARYID INTO :Result;
END^
```

Comment: Hi ain, this works, but when trying to use the variable A (or value1) (value1 Varchar(64)) in "where Field = value1 into :Result;" I get the column unknown again.
If I double quote the "value1" it would mean literal. So how would I be able to use the variable?

Comment: Prefix it with colon, thats how you separate parameters/variables from columns in SQL statements in PSQL, ie `:A` or `:value1`

Comment: Hi ain, that work for the creation of the SP.
But when executing it with flamerobin like: SELECT p.RESULT FROM TESTSP(VALUE1) p gives a column unknown "VALUE1".

And I would like to loop though this function 4 times for 4 values and get 4 results.
Do you have advice on how to handle that?

I updated my Original post with all the responses, to compile a full example for others with the same question.

Comment: Flamerobin doesn't know how to substitue the `value1` with some value, you have to use some value constant instead of variable name there, ie `SELECT p.RESULT FROM TESTSP('foo') p` . As of looping, thats kind of hard to with inpot coming from different parameters for each step so you better unroll the loop - write the same set of statement for each step of the loop, using different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple instruction for then and/ or else clause you must use `BEGIN ... END`-block!

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE TESTSP 
 ( A Varchar(64) ) 
RETURNS 
 ( RESULT Integer )
AS 

BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT PRIMARYID FROM TABLENAME WHERE FIELD = 'Some string')) then
  BEGIN
    SELECT PRIMARYID FROM TABLENAME WHERE FIELD = 'Some string' into :primaryid;
    result = PRIMARYID;
  END
ELSE 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLENAME (FIELD) VALUES ('Some string');
    result = gen_id(GEN_TABLEID, 0);
  END
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: Hello Tico,

Thank you for your reply, I tried that before, but it didn't worked either.
Than I get the error that the column PRIMARYID is unknown

Answer (score 1):

I think your stored procedure should look like this:

```
SET TERM ^ ; 
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTSP 
  ( A Varchar(64) ) 
  RETURNS ( result Integer ) 
AS 
BEGIN 
  IF (EXISTS (SELECT PRIMARYID 
              FROM TABLENAME 
              WHERE FIELD = 'Some string')) then 
     SELECT PRIMARYID 
       FROM TABLENAME 
       WHERE FIELD = 'Some string' 
       into :result;
  ELSE BEGIN
     result = gen_id(GEN_TABLEID, 1); 
     INSERT INTO TABLENAME 
       (PRIMARYID, FIELD) 
       VALUES (:result,  'Some string'); 
  END
END^ 
SET TERM ; ^
```